# Gradle build finish with 117 errors ( Android studio 1.4)

Tags: android

I just created a project.This is the first page I get.

the errors goes like this

```
Error:(6, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:textAlignment'.
Error:(10, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingEnd'.
Error:(10, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingEnd'.
Error:(13, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingStart'.

on gradle console following error occurs
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name \u0027android:TextAppearance.Material.Inverse\u0027."

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name \u0027android:TextAppearance.Material.Large.Inverse\u0027."
and many more.
```

Comment: Check your builde.gradle file under dependency section. Make sure you have correctly added support library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the build tool version .
If your android version is 1.0 or 1.01 than you should try to build on a lower version probably API 21 or less .

Answer (score 2):

Post your `builde.gradle` .And i guess change your `buildToolsVersion`

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

defaultConfig {
   // applicationId "package name"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

or set `buildToolsVersion to 23.0.1`